# How to get all the data between two years in Entity frame work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table called Record. I want to get all the records between 2009 to current year. How do I do that in Entity framework? 
Right now my query is like this, with this i am getting only 2018 records. I want to get all the records between 2009 to current year.

```
public ActionResult DataSheet(int year = 0)
{
    if (year < 2009 || year > DateTime.Now.Year)
        year = DateTime.Now.Year;

    var records= _db.record.Where(p => p.date.Value.Year == year).ToList();

    return View(records);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read up on SQL the difference between using `AND & OR`

Comment: The `== year` part can  really only show you 1 year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
 var records= _db.record.Where(p => p.date.Value.Year > 2009 
                                 && p.date.Value.Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
                        .ToList();
```

If you need also the records in 2009 and in the current year, you should also add `=`, `>=` and `<=` in the above expression.